# Как сделать Parallax анимацию

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Хочу сделать анимацию вроде той, какая на гифке внизу, но не для `ViewPager`-а, а для замещения одного `View` другим.

[image]

Comment: Не подскажу реализацию, но можно посмотреть готовые библиотеки по этому запросу: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=parallax

Comment: @VladimirParfenov спасибо за ссылку, но я не смог найти ничего подходящего. Что реализовать такую анимацию, нужны анимация перемещения и "обрезывания" края. С первой всё понятно, а как сделать вторую?